# Set a default maxWidth for all Containers in Material UI (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The [Container docs](https://material-ui.com/api/container/) state that the default `maxWidth` is `lg`. Is there a way via theme to globally set it to `md`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Globals docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props) specify how to globally set default props. In this case it would be:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiContainer: {
      maxWidth: "md",
    },
  },
})
```